# How to compare the input with the columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

We are building an mobile aswell as web application. So basically the application is going to be used for online restaurant reservation(Diploma Thesis).

This right here are our tables:

```
DROP TABLE RESERVATION;
DROP TABLE RESTAURANT;
DROP TABLE CUSTOMER;
DROP TABLE RESTAURANTOwner;

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext;


CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CUSTOMER_ID SERIAL primary key NOT NULL,
CUSTOMER_FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(20),
CUSTOMER_SECONDNAME VARCHAR(20),
CUSTOMER_EMAIL CITEXT, 
CUSTOMER_USERNAME VARCHAR(80), 
CUSTOMER_PASSWORD VARCHAR(100), 
CUSTOMER_PHONE VARCHAR(20),
CUSTOMER_SALT INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE RESTAURANTOwner (
OWNER_ID SERIAL primary key NOT NULL,
OWNER_FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(20),
OWNER_SECONDNAME VARCHAR(20),
OWNER_EMAIL CITEXT, 
OWNER_USERNAME VARCHAR(80), 
OWNER_PASSWORD VARCHAR(100), 
OWNER_PHONE VARCHAR(20),
OWNER_SALT INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE RESTAURANT (
RESTAURANT_ID SERIAL primary key NOT NULL,
OWNER_ID INT NOT NULL,
RESTAURANT_NAME VARCHAR(40),
RESTAURANT_LAYOUT VARCHAR(255),
CONSTRAINT FK_OWNER_ID FOREIGN key (OWNER_ID) references RESTAURANTOwner(OWNER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE RESERVATION (
RESTAURANT_ID INT NOT NULL,
CUSTOMER_ID INT NOT NULL,
RESERVATION_TIME Time,
RESERVATION_DATE DATE,
PRIMARY KEY(RESTAURANT_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,RESERVATION_TIME,RESERVATION_DATE),
CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMER_ID FOREIGN key (CUSTOMER_ID) references CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_RESTAURANT_ID FOREIGN key (RESTAURANT_ID) references RESTAURANT(RESTAURANT_ID)
);
```

So I want to create stored procedure which is going to compare the input. E.g. I want to check if the restaurant name is longer than 40 characters.

Since I'm not that good in PL/SQL I've run in some trouble.

Here is the things I've tried:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_name();
CREATE PROCEDURE test_name()
      LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
declare 
 c1 cursor for 
    SELECT RESTAURANT_NAME FROM RESTAURANT ;
  BEGIN
  FOR v_RESTAURANT_NAME IN c1
  LOOP
    if(length(v_RESTAURANT_NAME) > 41) THEN
        raise notice 'Restaurant name % is longer than 40 characters.', v_RESTAURANT_NAME;
        END IF;
          END LOOP;
  END;
$$;


CALL test_name('testtest')
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong. It says that the function length() doesn't exist, I've checked the documenation and it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using a procedure add a check constraint to your column

```
  Alter table tabname
  Add constraint chk_length check(length(restaurant_name) 
  >41)
```

Comment: Is this going to change the structure of the database

Comment: Not the structure but will affect the data inserted in a way that restaurant length should be greater than 41 as you want either way its dropable will not affect the structure

Comment: Where should I put the lines you've provided me in the restaurant table ?

Comment: Run it separately n first change the tabname to your table name where restaurantname column exists and remember the constraint name `chk_length` so that if later you dont require this need you could easily drop the constraint without affecting your table

Comment: As it stands you need neither function nor check constraint.  If you attempt to insert, or update to a name longer than 40 Postgres will throw as exception: `SQL Error [22001]: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(40)`